# MVVM-Light: The target "RunCodeAnalysis" does not exist in the project when i do build?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm-light

Just built myself a mvvmlight app  and if i press f5 TO COMPILE and run all works ok, it displays the wpf window

but if i do a BUILD i get an error

```
 Error  1   The target "RunCodeAnalysis" does not exist in the project.
```

I am using the visual studio 2010 professional version RTM

The only thing i see strange is the target framework which is set to .NET framework 4 client profile

Anybody know why this happens??

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that I forgot to turn the Code Analysis option off when I published the project templates last time. I am about to publish a new service pack (for the phone), so I can turn it off again. I think that your version of VS10 does not support code analysis out of the box.

In the mean time, try this:

- Open the CSPROJ file in a text editor (Notepad, etc)
- Locate the line that reads "true" and delete it.
- Close the CSPROJ file and reload it in Visual Studio.

Let me know if that solves the issue.

Thanks,
Laurent

Comment: thanks!  yep that was it...  yes i am using vs 2010 RTM Professional which doesn't support code analysis ....